# ¿Como corregir el error en activity_main.xml design?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

El error presente es:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.(ActionBarContainer.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.(BridgeActionBar.java:89)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.(AppCompatActionBar.java:68)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:277)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.(Layout.java:161)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:288)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

No me deja realizar diseños y no se pueden ver los elementos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu archivo `build.gradle` cambia la versión de `appcompat-v7` a `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1`, ya que `28.0.0-alpha3` aun tiene problemas en cuanto a la vista de diseño.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podes hacer es cambiar dentro de  /res/values/styles.xml

esto

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

por esto

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

El problema esta en las versiones de buildTools y support library appCompat que usas

Tambien podes probar en el gradle cambiar tu appCompat por este

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

y usar el `buildToolsVersion`

```
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
```

Con estos cambios deberia resolver tu problema, prueba el primero y si no funciona el segundo